# Como serializar datos de un datagrid a JSON con C#?

Tags: c#, json

Estoy intentando obtener en formato JSON todas las filas de un datagrid en c#.
Con el siguiente codigo ya logro obtener el formato correcto del JSON pero no obtengo todos los datos del datagrid.
Solo me manda los datos de la ultima fila del datagrid, tomando en cuenta que el datagrid puerde tener n cantidad de filas con datos entonces no me esta funcionando correctamente(este ejemplo tiene 3 filas el datagrid pero solo me trae la ultima fila y los datos no los pone correctamente).

Aqui les dejo el codigo quizas no sea demasiado lo que me falte pero no encuentro como.

```
public class Formatjson
    {
        public string Folio { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
    }
    public class ListJson
    {
        public List<Formatjson> Infodatagrid { get; set; }
    }
```

Asi recorro el datagrid:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            var RootObject = new ListJson();
            RootObject.Infodatagrid = new List<Formatjson>();
            var folio = new Formatjson() { Folio = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[item.Index].Cells["Column5"].Value.ToString()) };
            var nombre = new Formatjson() { Nombre = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[item.Index].Cells["Column6"].Value.ToString()) };
            var apellido = new Formatjson() { Apellido = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[item.Index].Cells["Column7"].Value.ToString()) };
            RootObject.Infodatagrid.Add(folio);
            RootObject.Infodatagrid.Add(nombre);
            RootObject.Infodatagrid.Add(apellido);

            josnencode = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootObject);


        }
```

Este es el resultado en formato json:

```
{
"Infodatagrid": [{
    "Folio": "239",
    "Nombre": null,
    "Apellido": null
}, {
    "Folio": null,
    "Nombre": "Juan",
    "Apellido": null
}, {
    "Folio": null,
    "Nombre": null,
    "Apellido": "Perez"
}]
}
```

Me deberia de traer el Json con informacion de las 3 filas que tengo en el datagrid.

**EDITADO**
Esta es la imagen del datagrid, si sirve de ayuda, solo es un datagrid comun.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes que poner todo el codigo dentro del foreach, seria algo como esto

```
var RootObject = new ListJson();
RootObject.Infodatagrid = new List<Formatjson>();

foreach (var row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    var item = new Formatjson() 
    { 
        Folio = row.Cells["Column5"].Value.ToString(),
        Nombre = row.Cells["Column6"].Value.ToString(),
        Apellido = row.Cells["Column7"].Value.ToString()
    };
    RootObject.Infodatagrid.Add(item);
}

josnencode = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootObject);
```

como veras la lista se instancia fuera del loop

Comment: entiendo lo que comentas pero el resultado es parecedo al de arriba.  {
 "Infodatagrid": [{
  "Folio": null,
  "Nombre": "Juan",
  "Imagen": null
 }, {
  "Folio": null,
  "Nombre": null,
  "Apellido": "Perez"
 }, {
  "Folio": "239",
  "Nombre": null,
  "Apellido": null
 }]
}  
El data grid si tiene datos en las filas.

Comment: edite el ejemplo, analizalo ahora a ver como resulta

Comment: ya habia realizado el cambio tambien, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas de esta manera la carga de datos en tu DataGridView:

```
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private readonly BindingList<Formatjson> TuEnlaceAlgrid;
...

private void CargarGrid(){
    var TuListadeDatos = new List<Formatjson>();//aqui tu lista con datos
    TuEnlaceAlgrid = new BindingList<Formatjson>(TuListadeDatos);
    this.dataGridView2.DataSource = TuEnlaceAlgrid;
}
```

Pudes hacer esto:

```
private string MiInfo(){
     string jsonString= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TuEnlaceAlgrid);
     retunr jsonString;
}
```

Saludos